# Botframework - No POST call after installation

Tags: botframework, slack

Why isn't a JSON sent when an user installs the bot using the Add-to-slack button?

It would be great if the Message Handler gets a JSON like the one below:

    `{'recipient': 
         {'name': '<BOTNAME>', 'id': 'B3914PXXX:T36U94XXX'}, 
          'from': ..., 
          'timestamp': '2017-03-24T17:27:04.0994878Z', 
          'type': 'install', 
          'serviceUrl': 'https://slack.botframework.com', 'attachments': [], 'entities': [], 
          'channelData': {'ApiToken': 'xoxb-110276315777-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
'SlackMessage': {'channel': 'D3877AXXX', 'user': 'U37LYRXXX', 'ts': '1490376423.739835', 'source_team': 'T36U94XXX', 'team': 'T36U94XXX', 'type': 'install', 'text': ''}}, 
    ...
    }`

This enables, the bot server to know who installs the bot and instantly send them a Greeting message and for more reasons, this seems like a good option.

The `type` field is generally set to `typing` or `message`. Having a `install` value would help developers in handling a new install elegantly.

Is this already achievable through some other means?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you should be receiving the ConversationUpdate event that should tell you when the bot or any user is added to the conversation.  That's not quite the same as what you're looking for as it's scoped to the channel instead of to an entire team.

We'll add something to the backlog to think about a similar message to what you describe; we need to think about how it generalizes across channels.

Comment: Thanks jim, I haven't looked for the ConversationUpdate event. But the problem am facing again is that, we have to force our users to add the bot to a channel. In a way that is limiting, as we want to engage our users by making the bot start the first conversation with them.